# Photoshop making isometric?

Tags: photoshop, isometric

[image]

Hi everyone. I'm trying to learn isometric picture on photoshop.
I've found an example on web, just as an image. At this image, left square is my tile. I should transform this to the diamond at right.

But I'm wondering that, how can I make it most pratically?
I've transform the rotate to 45'.
What should I do now?
I've used distort to the the same but I don't know which values I should enter.

X: ? Y: ? W: ? Y: ? H:? ANGLE: ?

my square is 200px/200px. and which values I must enter to make it diamond like in the picture (is there any math formule?)

Answer (score 6):

[image]

So:

1. Rotate angle 45
2. Resize image: W=100%, H=58%

or use this [script](http://adobe.ly/1rTCKDE)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can transform x'=x and y'=x+y/2. Look the spiral search: [Optimizing search through large list of lat/long coords to find match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139602/optimizing-search-through-large-list-of-lat-long-coords-to-find-match/18145430#18145430).