# algorithm for obtain geographical coordinates of a spiral which starts from a point in space

Tags: algorithm, geolocation, coordinates, geospatial, spiral

Does anyone know a **algotiritm** that is capable of returning the **geographic coordinates** of a **spiral**, which starts at a point in space?

Example of starting point:
$ lat = "-22.851479";
$ lng = "-43.232038";

Spiral type: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_spiral

There are several responses that are able to return the points in the X, Y.
like: [Looping in a spiral](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398299/looping-in-a-spiral)

But I'm interested in **geographic coordinates**.

Perhaps the conversion of coordinated planar X, Y coordinates for geographical also serve to solve my problem.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to use squares of equal area or hexagons or some other tiling scheme. And where are you planning on starting the spiral from. I think you can do it by reprojecting to a 2D surface, but the choice of projection is relevant.

Answer (score 0):

You can transform the x-coordinate like this x1=x+y/2 and move the axis. I'm not sure about the bucket-size but it should work with geocoordinate:[Optimizing search through large list of lat/long coords to find match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18139602/optimizing-search-through-large-list-of-lat-long-coords-to-find-match/18145430).